# OAuth 2.0 How to invalidate granted auth tokens using password grant

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, authorization, dotnetopenauth

For the following scenario:

1. User Agent (Browser, User) making Ajax requests to Resource Server
2. ASP.NET MVC application using DotNetOpenAuth (Client)
3. OAuth-Authorization Server
4. ASP.NET Web API (Resource Server)

The user enters his credentials to login into the MVC Application.
The MVC application makes a token request using the password grant to the Authorization Server using the user's credentials and the Client.Id + Client.Secret of the MVC application.
The OAuth token is received by the MVC application from the Authorization Server.
The token is passed back to the client, which stores the token in LocalStorage.

Now my questions:

1. How to invalidate the token, so the user cannot access the Resource Server (Web API) anymore. As the token now resides in LocalStorage the MVC app has no control over the token anymore. A solution might be to use very short expiration times or use some `SignalR` stuff to invalidate the token, but there would be enough time for a malicious user who has obtained access to the token to make bad things. I think there is no way of invalidating the token instantly. And the Resource Server would not know that the token is invalidated until it really expires.
2. What would be the flow if the token has expired? I could check the expiration date using JavaScript in the Browser/ or wait for a 401 response from the Resource Server, and make an Ajax refresh token request to my MVC application (Client), which then requests a new token from the Authorization Server (using Client.Id + Client.Secret + UserCredentials) and passes the new token back to the Browser, which can then be used for further requests to the Resource Server (Web API). Would this be the right approach?

On logout/password change, I could delete the token from LocalStorage and invalidate the token on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have practically answered your own questions!
You can't invalidate the token on the server side (unless DNOA deals with Token revocations which I don't think it does).
The token is a bearer token so whoever has it can use it on the resource server until the expiry time is reached. Keeping it short-lived is the best way of doing it.

Also when using the password grant,you should only use the user's credentials once, to get the initial token and refresh token. You can then relate the refresh token to the user id in your MVC app and use the refresh token in future to get a new access token.

Comment: Yes, without coupling OAuth Server and Resource Server it will not be possible, otherwise you had to check the token against the OAuth server when reaching the resource server in order to check if has been revoked...